# Can't get a GoogleAPI chart to appear in KML popup

Tags: google-api, kml

I am having trouble getting a google API made table to appear in my KML popup. I have made other GoogleAPI feature such as pie and bar charts appear but this table wont load in and I'm just left with a blank space.

I have listed the code for the table below which does load on the chrome browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Site');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Figure 1');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Figure 2');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Figure 3');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Figure 4');
    data.addRows([
        ['A','0','2.75','3.88','1.59'],['B','0','4','4.54','1.21'], ['C','0','0.5','4.2','8.98'],['D','0','5','0.06','0.01'],['E','0','5','0.26','0.06'],['F','0','5','0.07','0.02'],['G','0','3.68','0.61','0.24'],['H','0','0.5','1.29','3.02'],['I','0','0.5','0.42','1.0'],['J','0','5','0.72','0.15'],['K','0','1.66','60.73','38.74'],['L','0','5','0.14','0.03'],['M','0','5','0.25','0.06'],['N','0','5','0.05','0.01'],['O','0','5','0.06','0.01'],['P','0','1.55','0.31','0.23'],['Q','0','5.29','82.96','16.53'],['R','0','2.85','0.38','0.17'],['S','0','0.5','0.31','0.71'],['T','0','3.77','4.54','1.49']
        ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '1000px', height: '500px'});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>TABLE </h1>
  <div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
```

I'm expecting the table to appear in the popup window of the KML point. at the moment it is just completely blank when I open it up.

Anyone encountered this before or have any ideas?

Comment: How are you displaying your KML?  Google Maps Javascript API v3?  Google Earth? Some other way?  In general KML infowindow content is sanitized (javascript removed).

Comment: I am displaying it in google earth. Ah ok, so I don't know if this is relevant but when creating a  GoogleAPI pie chart, using the Java caller "https://www.google.com/jsapi" works in google earth but using "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" does not even though both work when viewing the results in chrome.

Comment: Which version of Earth are you displaying it in? Google Earth Pro (v7.x), or the new Google Earth for web & mobile (v9.x)? In Earth for web, there are CORS restrictions on which content can be loaded.  If the CORS headers aren't set right by the server providing the chart image, then they won't be displayed.  You should be able to see CORS errors in the Chrome developer tools > Console. If you have a sample KML file to share, that might help debug.